# Integrating a frontend js framework (Vue) for django

Tags: django, vue.js

I am a Laravel developer and used Vue as my frontend framework in the past.
However, I got interested in learning Python, specially its web framework equivalent - Django. Compared to Laravel, Django is pretty much way better in all aspects  - it's fast, it's one of those 'all-in-one' type of framework, plus it's PYTHON. A 15-minute task in Laravel can be accomplished in Django for 5 minutes.

One thing that's just bugging me is how to integrate Vue on its templates. I tried the normal `CDN` method but it doesn't actually work. I figured maybe because django's syntax -`{{ sample variable here }}` and Vue's are the same. I tried writing delimiters like `delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],` but it just made it more complex and still will not work.
I tried doing the `webpack` method which install a separate vue project within the django project, then used several (like a lot of third-party plugins) to somewhat connect the vue project, to the django project. It is so tedious on its process and it seems like it's not the why it should be. I kinda miss it on Laravel where you could just create an `app.blade.php` main template, import `app.js` on it, then just take it from there.

Is there a way to just integrate Vue on django's templates quickly like you can on Laravel?

Comment: Why not decouple your app entirely? Use Django (perhaps Django rest framework) for your backend and Vue for the front end. Make your backend calls in Vue with Axios. From my personal experience this will save you time and headache in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

We use Vue with Django via cdn, and it is pretty easy to set up as you can do everything in the template file.

You have to be sure to import Vue via script tag somewhere on the page and then either define your own delimiters (as you've done) or use the `{% verbatim %} {% endverbatim %}` tags around any variables you do not want django to try and evaluate. You can either write your Vue function in a script tag on the page or import an external file via script tag the way you would import any other js file into a django template. If you posted your template code, I might be able to provide more guidance.